# REST + HTTP Basic Auth - necessary to do user lookup every request?

Tags: rest, basic-authentication

I'm making a REST API for my web app and since it should be stateless I'm sending the user's credentials with HTTP Basic Auth.

Is it correct that I need to validate the username/password with a lookup in my users database for every request? This seems like a lot of unnecessary requests considering I can validate it once and just keep it in a session if I break the "stateless rule".

Comment: Which is your server side technologie?

Comment: how many users per second do you expect?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use session cookies for authentification you need to validate each request. But you could cache the credentials somewhere in your server code, so that you don't need to query the database on every call.

Basically you should remember not to store the data too long, e.g. the user could change her/his credentials. If you have a cache missmatch you need to do another database lookup.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead keep a global cache of usernames/passwords where you verify the credentials. Your requests will still be stateless but you will get better performance than just going against the database (or another source) in each request to validate the user.

Another option would be to create a Login method where you return a encrypted authentication token. After that every other method would expect this token and verify that instead of the password. This approach would also enable you to use different authentication mechanisms not just http basic.